# How to create connectors that cross other connectors properly?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Using Draw.io can you create a connector that will "jump" over another connector without simply crossing it or going around it?

Comment: No, but there is a feature request for it - https://draw.uservoice.com/forums/266072-feature-requests/suggestions/6498306-edge-bridges-jump-loops

Comment: much obliged. added my votes. Please change your comment to an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line jumps are now [natively supported](https://www.facebook.com/drawioapp/posts/1636030279754835).

When a line is selected, there is a "Line jumps" option under the style tab.

[image: line jumps]